# How to show the address of memory created on heap?

Tags: c++

I know this is a very basic question but I am not getting it right.

```
char * data = new char[5];
data = "hamz";
```

Here I created a pointer to char, data. Data is a pointer and it stores the address of a char array on heap.

When I `cout<<data;`

Why does it not show me address? It shows me "hamz".

Same with this

```
cout<<&data[0];
```

How could I know the address which is stored in data? As it stores the address of the array on heap.

Comment: `data = "hamz";`and now you leaked memory. Use std::string, get a good C++ book.

Comment: `data = "hamz"` assigns the address of the string literal `"hamz"` to your variable `data`. The original address to the memory allocated by `new` is lost. Your compiler should've also warned you about assigning a pointer of a string literal (which is read-only) to a non-`const` pointer.

Comment: `data = "hamz";` is just wrong. If you can't see why, then read [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Why are you even using `new` here? Why not just a `std::string`?

Comment: I know i can use string here. But I m just curious why data cannot show what is actually stored in it? The address of the memory on heap. @jesper

Answer (score 3):

The `ostream` overload of `<<` for `const char*` works in a special way: it outputs the memory as characters up to the next NUL-terminator.

If you want to switch this behaviour off, and output the actual address of the pointer, then cast to `const void*`:

```
std::cout << (const void*)(data);
```

---

Note that you should really write

```
const char* data = "hamz";
```

and bin the `new`. Currently you leak memory like a colander leaks water.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `std::cout`'s member function call syntax to output the `data` pointer value instead of a string literal:

```
std::cout.operator<<(data);
```

This will call the 7th [std::basic_ostream::operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) overload that accepts the parameter of type `const void*`. Prefer [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to raw character arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First, just to answer your question, you need to cast the `char*`-type to `void*`, i.e. write `cout << (void*)data;`. Otherwise, when the data type is `char*`, `cout` treats `data` as a `'\0'`-terminated sequence of characters.

There are, however, other issues:
Statement

```
data = "hamz";
```

lets `data` point to a string literal, but it does not copy the string `"hamz"` into the memory allocated on the heap. You actually loose the pointer to the allocated memory in the heap and produce a memory leak. For copying contents, you'd have to use `strcpy(data,"hamz")`.

Then, as `data` will point to an (by definition) immutable string literal, data type should be `const char*`, i.e. `const char* myData = "hamz"`.